# Help with understanding the definition of a Hodge groupoid

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, groupoids

I am reading [this PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.05757.pdf) and I can't understand definition 6.21:

> (Hodge groupoid). $(X/S)_{Hod}$ is a groupoid whose object object is $X\times \Bbb A^1_S$ and whose morphism object $N_{Hod}$ is given by the following procedure. First,
> blow up $X \times_S X \times_S \Bbb A^1 S$ at $∆ \times 0$. Next, take the complement of the strict transform of $X \times X \times_S 0$. Finally, take the PD completion along $∆ \times_S \Bbb A^1$.

I don't understand what is the "object object" and "morphism object".
Does it mean the objects and the morphisms of the fiber over and object in the base category (since we deal with stacks)?. I have some notions of category theory and for me there are "objects" and "isomorphisms" in a groupoid. I am mainly interested in understanding what $N_{Hod}$ represents in the Moduli stack of integrable $\lambda$-connections (denoted $M_{Hod}$) in this thesis. In particular, I want to know if Proposition $6.22$ ($N_{Hod}$ is flat over $\Bbb A^1$) means that $M_{Hod}$ is flat over $\Bbb A^1_S$?

Thank you for your lights.

Comment: I guess "object object" and "morphism object" indicate that these are *internal* groupoids in some category. More precisely, the author probably means "groupoid schemes", i.e. groupoids in the category of schemes (see Definition 5.1).

Comment: Many thatnks @ArnaudD., I missed this important part on groupoid schemes

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.) I've taken the liberty of improving your title in this post.

Comment: Thank you @KReiser, I will make sure my titles are more informative